# Like me or not I am everywhere. Can you guess?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I am quite attractive

I memorize things galore

Don't like ten (and a half)

And number twenty four

A host, water or air

Is all I need and care

Colourful I am

But dangerous, beware

Comment: The three shades of blue =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from what @Apep got, as well as OP's hints ... are you perhaps

> Rust (iron oxide)?

Like me or not I am everywhere. Can you guess?

> Rust is found just about everywhere; some people like it (as a decorative patina, for example), while others don't.

I am quite attractive

I memorize things galore

> I suspected from earlier answers that this one had to do with computers, but I had to look it up.  According to Wikipedia, iron oxides are used in the production of magnetic storage media in computers - that is, computer *memory*.  (So perhaps the "magnetic" part is what the "attractive" is referring to - as magnets *attract* things?  Or maybe the line just means that rust itself is considered visually attractive by some people.)

Don't like ten (and a half)

And number twenty four

> Chromium is element #24 on the periodic table; stainless steel contains a minimum of 10.5% chromium.  Rust wouldn't like stainless steel as stainless steel is designed not to rust.

A host, water or air

Is all I need and care

> In order to develop, all rust needs is an iron "host" (e.g. a nail) and water (found either in its liquid state, or as water vapor in the air).

Colourful I am

> Rust has a lovely reddish color

But dangerous, beware

> Rusty metal is known to cause tetanus, a dangerous disease; also, rust can cause iron structures (buildings, cars, bridges...) to weaken and even break!

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Quartz ?

I am quite attractive

> Quartz is shiny, bright and attractive

I memorize things galore

> Quartz-clock based memory systems can store huge amounts of data

Don't like ten (and a half)

> Ten is the normal starting time of work (on a working day) and a half represents 10:05 AM... which is quite not liked by many ?!

And number twenty four

> In quartz-based clocks, all times can be represented except 24:00 hrs

A host, water or air

> Can function anywhere (in a container / air / water )

Is all I need and care

> However, it needs to be protected

Colourful I am

> It exhibits all colours in certain form when normal white light gets incident on it

But dangerous, beware

> It can be harmfult if swallowed / used in counter/timer-based explosive devices

And finally, when it comes to the title of the riddle,

> quartz is everywhere (in the sand)

Comment: Wouldn't ten-and-a-half on a clock be 10:30 instead of 10:05?

Comment: @puzzledPig, well, the clue said about TEN and a half (1/2 of ten) which I have taken as 5 (and literally 05)... and proceeded.

Comment: ok, I didn't think of that interpretation, but it could work too! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Chromium

I am quite attractive

> Chromium is used in jewellery.

I memorize things galore

> Chromium is used in the magnetic storage layer of a hard disk drive.

Don't like ten (and a half)

> Unsure about this one.

And number twenty four

> Chromium is #24 on the periodic table of elements. (Hinted at by Deepak Mahulikar [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53623/like-me-or-not-i-am-everywhere-can-you-guess#comment165842_53657).)

A host, water or air

> Unsure about this one.

Is all I need and care

> Unsure about this one.

Colourful I am

> Chromium was named after the Greek word for colour because many compounds are intensely coloured.

But dangerous, beware

> Chromium(VI) is toxic and carcinogenic.

Comment: Boy you are  on right track Apep. " dont like 24 and 10.5" Why wouldnt I like Chromium? 10.5 of it?

Comment: Stainless steel has a minimum of 10.5% Chromium - might that be related?

Comment: @puzzledPig That is most likely it, but it causes me to doubt my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> LASER !

I am quite attractive

> Usually visual laser beam is attractive

I memorize things galore

> Laser-based communication enables to transmit and store data(?!)

Don't like ten (and a half)

> Ten is X (in Roman Numerals) and X-Rays have its own limitations as compared to LASER

And number twenty four

> Maximum dimension (in units / measurements) of blades, beyond which it cannot penetrate, a kind of WILD guess !

A host, water or air

> LASER can pass thorugh a host/water/air

Is all I need and care

> We should be handling it with care

Colourful I am

> LASER can occur in various colors

But dangerous, beware

> It cane be harmful, if not handled properly !

Comment: Or it could be U.V. Rays as well !

Comment: Good guess Mea Culpa  but

Comment: what about "(and a half)"?

Comment: Clue wise 24 is an important number and so is 10.5

Answer (score 0):

Don't like ten (and a half)

And number twenty four

> These could be referring to a 10.5 oz. can and a case of 24 cans maybe

Comment: In what document full numbers show up???

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar Full numbers are used in *any* formal writing. Not sure where you're headed with this.

Comment: Just giving a clue. 24 shows up in what document or Table?